# Why am I not able to paste copied queries into BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently taking Google's Data Analytics course, I'm enjoying it well and am able to troubleshoot most issues on my own. One issue I keep running into is that I am never able to PASTE any of the queries from the lessons into BigQuery's SQL editor. I'm having no issue copying, but I've never been able to successfully paste a query. I've tried writing them myself; to varying degrees of success. However, at this point I can't keep dancing around my lack of understanding. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: no idea. I was able to copy from https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7586738 and paste to https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery with no issue. what type of computer are you using? what browser? where are you copying from? which SQL editor are you using?

Comment: I'm just copying directly from the lesson into BigQuery's SQL editor and it's not doing anything. I'm using Google Chrome on an HP Pavilion All in one desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem while trying to copy and paste from and to Bigquery while taking Google's Data Analytics course.
This issue of not being able to paste only happens to me when I compose new query and line 1 is blank.
One way to get around it that works for me is to type anything on line 1 and to paste your text on line 2 and onwards. Delete line 1 and you should be able to run it without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

Use shortcut commands <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the text into BigQuery after copying it.

Comment: Can't imagine OP didn't tested that solution before posting. You should better add some info or remove your answer since it's not really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).